# how to create project in ionic,cordova and android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed ionic, cordova and android.
But ionic is not creating android project.
I have attached the error.

`C:\Users\shri\myapp>ionic platform add android
Creating android project...
C:\Users\shri.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at C:\Users\shri.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:158:19
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\shri.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\shri.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\shri.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
    at C:\Users\shri.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:821:14
    at flush (C:\Users\shri.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
Error: C:\Users\shri.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\shri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)`

Comment: I had this exact same thing. Error message is not helpful. I ran "cordova platform add android" and it said I needed API 19, which I found out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677999/cordova-please-install-android-target-19

Comment: @MarkRobson : That tutorial helped me. I was having the problem of path variables. I dint include platform-tools path in the environment variable before. Now it works. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include ANDROID_HOME in your PATH.  I recommend you do the following (assuming you're on Windows 8.1):

Right click the tile launcher icon in your task bar and choose **system**.  In the window that pops up, choose **Advanced system settings** on the left.  In the **System Properties** window click the **Environment Variables** button and choose to add a new system variable.  For the name choose ANDROID_HOME and for the value include the full path to your Android SDK directory.

Edit the PATH variable and add the following to the end of the value:

**;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools**

Restart your windows session and it should work now.