# Cordova Error Please Install Android target 19

Tags: android, cordova

My Cordova has suddenly stopped working.

It was working well when I was last working on it - around 2 months ago.

Now when I want to resume working on my project, it gives me the error:

```
> cordova platforms add android
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.7.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.7.1.tgz
Platform android already added.


> cordova run android
Running command: C:\Work\Eclipse\Workspace\Android\CordovaTmp\HelloWorld\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat
"C:\Work\Eclipse\Workspace\Android\CordovaTmp\HelloWorld\platforms\android\cordova\run"
ERROR: Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: C:\Work\Eclipse\Workspace\Android\CordovaTmp\HelloWorld\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project


> cordova -version
4.3.0
```

I have checked out these posts, but thats of no help: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688345/cordova-wants-android-19-i-have-android-20), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931155/cordova-3-5-0-install-error-please-install-android-target-19) and [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677999/cordova-please-install-android-target-19).

Also, I am unable to run 'android' on the cygwin shell even though I have added tools and platform-tools to my PATH variable in 'My Computer'

I am running Windows 8.1, cygwin and here is what my SDK Manager looks like:
[image]

My platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.foo.helloworld" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: check out manifest.xml for minimum and maximum sdk and the target sdk it might help

Answer (score 1):

The cordova run android command needed to be run from windows powershell and not cygwin.