# Cordova Error: Please install Android target: "android-23": PhoneGap :6.0.1

Tags: android, cordova, android-sdk-tools, phonegap-cli

I am trying to build apk with Phonegap 6.0.1
at path

```
/path/to/myproject/platforms/android/cordova
```

run command `build --release`get error as below 
[image]

here is screenshot of android sdk manager 
[image]
[image]
I also try change in file

```
yourApp/platforms/android/project.properties    
yourApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties
```

`target=android-23` to `target=android-24`

also update AndroidManifest.xml
to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
```

but same error

```
CordovaError: Please install Android target: "android-24".
```

can anyone help
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Have you added the tools and platform-tools directories to your path? i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20679414/417681

Comment: @wildabeast, I add sdk path tools with these steps Advance System Setting > Environment variables >System variables > edit valuable path & add ;C:\Development\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms  at end, but still same error

Comment: @wildabeast if I type "android" in run & cmd then Android SDK manager is also open

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053007/cordova-error-please-install-android-target-android-23-phonegap-6-0-1

Comment: @Dinesh, first you gotta ensure that you have android-24 sdk installed

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue for a LONG TIME now and I finally got a solution for myself.

I forgot to set the `ANDROID_HOME` system variable. It has to be set to the directory `android-sdk`.

Try adding the `ANDROID_HOME` variable and set it to your android-sdk root directory. (not tools or platform-tools)